# Can a TyphoonComponentFactory swap TyphoonDefinitions?

Tags: ios, objective-c, typhoon

I have a bunch of assemblies that have dependencies between them that I initiate through the TyphoonComponentFactory. Once I have my TyphoonComponentFactory I am able to ask the TyphoonComponentFactory for objects that implement XYZ protocol and it returns me the default implementation of that object that implements XYZ.

```
id<XYZProtocol>objectToAssemble {
    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[DefaultObject<XYZProtocol> class]]
}
```

Now I would like to go a little further. The consumers of my application know that they could be swapping the default implementation of XYZ Protocol that I am providing in my assemblies. They wrote their own class that implements that same XYZ Protocol so basically they have a class with the same method signatures but different implementations for each one of them. 
I know I can get all the assemblies that a TyphoonComponentFactory instantiated with, I know I can get the definitions for each one of them, and so the types of the classes they return and the protocols they implement. I just need this last step where i can swap the default Return Class for the new one the consumer is asking to swap. Then all my other assemblies that has a dependency on this default object would resolve with the new Class provided by the consumer.

Can the TyphoonPatcher modify an existing Definition to return a different Class other than the original provided? Can typhoonPatcher swap TyphoonDefinitions?

Comment: When you use activateWithCollaboratingAssmblies, you can provide a sub-class that overrides definitions with a new definition. You could also use the TyphoonPatcher. Take a look at these in the docs, and see if they suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks @JasperBlues. I have an issue opened in https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/issues/502 regarding this issue since I want to be able to create TyphoonDefinitions at runtime as well and seems that you guys only allow to create definitions if they are part of an Assembly.